# CORS Issue with Angular $http call to Instagram public feed

Tags: angularjs, api, xmlhttprequest, cors

I'm trying to implement a public feed of an intagram account into my simple Angular app. I created the app using `yo generate angular` I added one service to the controller to make the call using $http. This is some sort of Cross Origin Resource Sharing issue. I've set some `app.config` values as you can see.  Here is my js.

```
angular.module('codeApp')

  .config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = '*';
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
  })

  .controller('MainCtrl',
['$scope', '$http', '$sce',
  function ($scope, $http, $sce) {

    $scope.data = {};
    $scope.pics = [];

    var endPoint = 'https://www.instagram.com/joincornerstone/media';

    $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(endPoint);

    $http.jsonp(
      endPoint,
      {param: {jsonpCallbackParam: 'angular.callbacks._0'}})
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log('response')
      console.log(response)

      $scope.data = response.data;

      console.log('response.data')
      console.log(response.data)
    })
    .catch(function(xhr) {
      console.error(xhr);
    });

  }
]
```

);

then in my template I just iterate over the `$scope.pics` array

```
   <div class="instagram-feed">
      <div class="row">
        {{ pics }}
        <div ng-repeat="p in pics " class="pic">
            <a href="{{p.link}}" target="_blank">
              <img ng-src="{{p.images.low_resolution.url}}" class="" title="{{p.caption.text}}">
            </a>

        </div> 
      </div>
    </div>
```

2 problems going on. 1) I am getting an error on the $http call. This is what shows up in my console from the `console.error(xhr,status, err);`:

```
false 404 (name) {
    if (!headersObj) headersObj =  parseHeaders(headers);

    if (name) {
      var value = headersObj[lowercase(name)];
      if (value === void 0) {
        value = null;
      }
```

2) In the Network tab of Dev Tools, I can see the call does get made and IS successful (i.e. status code: 200), I can click thru and see the json obj returned, but it throws an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` which looking at the returned json:

```
{"status": "ok", "items": [{"can_delete_comments": false, "code":...etc
```

It is happening on the colon right after "status". Somehow Angular is not able to read the returned json from Intagram correctly. And it is thinking the api endpoint is not there(404) even though the browser clearly shows me that it is.

Can anyone help?

Comment: which browser did you use to test this?

Comment: Chrome Version 54.0.2840.71 (64-bit)

Comment: From the documentation it seems you missing callbackParam.....$http.jsonp() should be something like this $http.jsonp('some/trusted/url', {jsonpCallbackParam: 'callback'}).......https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get

Comment: Thx, I missed that in the docs. I did add the 2nd argument and also called $sce.trustAsResourceUrl() on the url. But got the same error still. First the Unexpected Token :  and then the err from the failed $http call

Comment: ... well, the $http() call is successful  but the response somehow can't be parsed and angular interprets it as false and the url to be 404

Comment: console.log the response in the `.success` method. You will see that the `.success` method doesn't give the handler function a response object. It spreads the response object over several arguments.

Comment: In versions of Angular before 1.5.8 the name of the callback should be the string JSON_CALLBACK. The `jsonpCallbackParam` config property is new for 1.5.8

Comment: If you look at my js (simplified) code again I did declare the callback obj in the $http config argument. I also tried this both adding it to the url as a querystring. The docs for $http do say that the JSON_CALLBACK string cannot be used but you can format the callback obj differently. Neither of these methods has worked. For some reason, Angular cannot parse the response headers and is not returning a response that the browser can recognize

Answer (score 0):

In v1.5.8 also have to use JSON_CALLBACK.

I myself have fallen into this trap when installed current stable v1.5.8, recent docs says JSON_CALLBACK string cannot be used, use attribute "jsonpCallbackParam", but these construction just doesn't work for me.

Then when I looked docs of exact version v1.5.8 everything fell into place. Nothing there about "jsonpCallbackParam": https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/docs/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp

Can't post comments, may be it will help you too.